# Angular directive, trigger scope function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom popup panel that I want to add functionality to close whenever the screen is clicked outside the panel. I created a directive to accomplish this, but I am having a hard time communicating that the close event happened.

```
<div ng-if="ui.showConfig" auto-hide="ui.showConfig=false">...</div>
```

JS

```
myApp.directive('autoHide',
    [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
              'autoHide': '&'
             },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var $overlay = $("<div style='position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:2000;'>");
                $overlay
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .one("click", function(e){ 
                        element.hide();
                        $overlay.unbind().remove(); 
                        // This is not firing...
                        // scope.autoHide(); 
                    });

                element.css("zIndex", "2001");

                element.on('$destroy', function() {
                    $overlay.unbind().remove();
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rageLqb4/)

The overlay click event is firing. The panel is hiding. But `ui.showConfig` is not getting set to false causing the user to click the button twice to open up the panel next time.

*Also, if there is another approach I should consider please let me know!*

Comment: Can you post your code in plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an event handler you need to call `scope.$apply()` so that angular gets informed about changes:

```
// This is not firing...
scope.autoHide(); 
scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest you at the first do not use the jquery appending in DOM extra elements or something else, and also I want to suggest use already build [angular bootstrap modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)
which will gave you more advantages. You can check the link and see the examples and how to include the module in your project. I'm pretty sure what the all functionality you need for popup bootstrap mpodal already has.

Answer (score 0):

i did try your jsfiddle and http://jsfiddle.net/yke1pm7g/1/ apparently the event fires, however i don't understand whats going on with `scope.autoHide()` ?